# как сделать так, чтобы в функцию попадали числа из всех добавленных Entry

Tags: python, tkinter

Подскажите пожалуйста: при нажатии кнопки Добавить, появляются новые Entry, в функцию попадает число только из последнего добавленного Entry, как сделать так, чтобы в функцию попадали числа из всех добавленных Entry

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
flats = []

def addFlat():
    global k2
    k2=Entry(root)
    k2.grid(column=1, sticky=E)
    flats.append(k2)

def spisokKvar():
    komun=int(k2.get())
    text_1.insert(END,komun)
Button(root,text='Добавить квартиру', command=addFlat).grid(row=10, column=0, sticky=W)
Button(root,text='Вывести список', command=spisokKvar).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=E)
text_1=Text(root,height=20,width=50)
text_1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3,sticky=N+E+S+W)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def addFlat():
    entry = Entry(root)
    entry.grid(column=1, sticky=E)
    flats.append(entry)

def spisokKvar():
    for entry in flats:
        text_1.insert(END, entry.get() + '\n')
```

Comment: К сожалению， этот код выводит все равно цифру последнего Entry， но уже умноженную на количество Entry )))

Comment: @user327535 такое возможно только в том случае, если вы продолжаете использовать глобальную переменную.

Comment: Спасибо большое， вы совершенно правы!